# @Html.ActionLink not opening in a fancybox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

My ActionLink doesn't open the required Action in a fancybox but instead is just working as a normal ActionLink, generating the content in another tab.

Here is how I included scripts _Layout:

```
<head>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")

@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/main/Navbar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
}
</head>

<body>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-media.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js"> </script>

<script src="~/Scripts/mail/app.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

My ActionResult is a GET action do not require any Model.ID parameter. This is the ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("FancyBox", "CreateExpCV", "_CandidateForm", null, new { @class = "fancybox" })
```

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

I do not understand whats the problem and I lose too much time on this very frustrating problem.

Comment: The issue is that fancybox is a jQuery plugin and depends on jQuery to work, You forgot to include jQuery (hint: jquery-ui **is not** jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionLink is working normally means your fancybox plugin is not working or conflicts with your other plugins(may be jquery-ui-*). Make sure that your plugins orientation is fine. 
Otherwise your scripts looks good :)

Comment: Both answers are partially true, scripts the way they were included are fine but something was still conflicting. I tried the code from @Alf Moh and fancybox was not a function. Then I just gave on ActionLink and I used a normal anchor tag and it worked, so something is conflicting with ActionLink but I don't have the patience to search why, because it already ruined 2 hours and I want to forget about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {    
$( ".fancybox" ).click(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 this.fancybox();
  });
 });
```